# Question on multiple entry Schengen visa

Tags: international-travel, schengen-visas

I'm an Indian residing in the UK. I have multiple entry short term Schengen visa which I have used multiple times to visit many Schengen countries as tourist. Is it possible for me to use the same visa to visit a Schengen country for attending a conference? Should I carry any specific documents?

Answer (score 1):

You have already used your multiple-entry visa, and I presume that the first trip was to the country which issued it. Things to keep in mind for subsequent visits:

- Check that your activities fall within the permissible activities on a short-stay visa. If you are just attending the conference that should be fine, if you are a paid speaker consult a specialist.
- Think through your documents **as if** you were making a fresh application. Premise and itinerary of the trip. Financing. Hotel reservations. Insurance. Return trip. Bring those documents with you to the border in case there are questions, but don't show them all unless you are asked.
- Bring a reasonable amount of cash in addition to any credit cards and the like.

In all likelihood, the immigration officials will simply stamp your passport. They may "chat" a bit with you to gauge your reactions. If so, tell them where you are going and that you have documents.